# Write Number in Expanded Form - Ruby NOT Printing Out Zeros

Tags: ruby, methods, numbers

Was practicing this question on Codewars:

You will be given a number and you will need to return it as a string in Expanded Form. For example:

```
expanded_form(12); # Should return '10 + 2'
expanded_form(42); # Should return '40 + 2'
expanded_form(70304); # Should return '70000 + 300 + 4'
```

My code:

```
def expanded_form(num)
  arry = Array.new
  arry << num.digits.reverse.each_with_index {|val, idx| val * (10 ** idx)} 
  arry.reverse.join(" + ")
end
```

I was testing it against the examples listed above, but I got back `"1 + 2"`, `"4 + 2"`, `"7 + 3 + 4"`, why doesn't the `each_with_index` seem to work?

**Edited 3:03 pm, Sep 11, 2018:**
I fixed all above mistakes, including removing zeros, and as @iGian pointed out, the .digits method already reverse all the numbers, what I have right now:

```
def expanded_form(num)
  num.digits.each_with_index.map{| val, idx | val * (10 ** idx)}.select{|x| x != 0}.reverse.join(" + ")
end
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`each_with_index` doesn't transform anything, it just iterates, so the result of `val * (10 ** idx)` is discarded.

What you need is to `map` this:

```
def expanded_form(num)
  num.digits.reverse.each_with_index.map do |val, idx|
    if (val > 0)
      val * (10 ** idx)
    end
  end.compact.reverse.join(' + ')
end
```

As `map` returns a new array you can skip the whole `Array.new` part and the `<<` insertion step which wasn't doing what you expected anyway.

Comment: `70304.digits # => [4, 0, 3, 0, 7]` already reversed. Just to remove zeroes:
`num.digits.reverse.each_with_index.map {|val, idx| val == 0 ? nil : val * (10 ** idx)}.compact.reverse.join(' + ')`

Comment: Thanks, I realized too after going through it again, I did a select method outside:

Comment: num.digits.each_with_index.map{| val, idx | val * (10 ** idx)}.select{|x| x != 0}.reverse.join(" + ")

Comment: Updated with zero suppression added. The `if` returns `nil` if that condition is false.

Comment: in @rhea.rao comment: `select { |x| x != 0 }` could also just be `reject(&:zero?)`, which imo is much cleaner...in the answer itself `each_with_index.map` could just be `map.with_index` and `digits.reverse` needs to just be `digits`

Comment: for 12 above logic will return "20 + 1" it's incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution

```
num.digits.each_with_index.with_object([]) do |(n,i),obj|
  obj.unshift("#{n}#{'0' * i}") if n > 0
end.join(" + ")
```

Since digits is in reverse we build the `Array` in reverse using unshift.

Since the final value is a `String` anyway we use `String#*` to add the needed zeros and we don't add the the zeros in to the `Array` at all.

Or use `String#ljust` to zero pad the output

```
num.digits.each.with_index(1).with_object([]) do |(n,i),obj|
  obj.unshift(n.to_s.ljust(i,'0')) if n > 0
end.join(" + ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution

```
def expanded_form(number)
  number_lengt = number
  @data_array = []
  loop_number(number)
  @data_array.join(' + ')
end

def loop_number(number)
  modulo_number = ('1' + '0'* (number.to_s.size - 1))&.to_i
  modulo_of_number = number % modulo_number
  @data_array.push(number - modulo_of_number)
  loop_number(modulo_of_number) unless (modulo_of_number % modulo_number).zero?
end
```